# Tex, Lyx misplaced \noalign with \input

Tags: lyx, tex-core

I have a file that, after some struggles, is now working in lyx. However, if I export to tex and run from texstudio I get the original misplace \noalign error I had previously got in Lyx. Here's the exported tex code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

%% TABLES %%
% Packages for tables
\usepackage{booktabs}% Pretty tables
\usepackage{tabularx}



% *****************************************************************
% siunitx
% *****************************************************************
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}} % Thanks to Joseph Wright & David Carlisle

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    group-digits            = false,
    input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
    table-align-text-post   = false,
    input-signs             = ,
}   


% *****************************************************************
% Estout related things
% *****************************************************************
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \expandableinput #1
{ \use:c { @@input } { \file_full_name:n {#1} } }
\AddToHook{env/tabular/begin}
{ \cs_set_eq:NN \estinput \expandableinput }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document


\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
    \small{
        \vspace{-1ex}{
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
                \toprule
                \estinput{#1}
                \bottomrule
                \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
        }
    }
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{MWE Table \label{MWE}}
        
        \centering
        \small{
            \estauto{/tables/MWE2.tex}{3}{c}
        }
    \end{table}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Here's MWE2.tex:

```
11 & 12 & 13 \\
21 & 22 & 23 \\
31 & 32 & 33 \\
```

Comment: Welcome to teX.SE!

Comment: Try removing the first `/` in `/tables/MWE2.tex` (or make sure MWE2.tex is truly in a tables folder under the root directory and that is what you intend) .

Comment: unrelated but size commands do not take an argument ` \small{` should be ` \small`

Comment: does lyx really write the file using latin9 encoding, not utf-8 ? (I don't know anything about lyx but that seems strange)

Comment: Regarding LyX and UTF-8: https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX24#unicode

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Dan, the backslash before tables was causing the issue. It should be:

```
\estauto{tables/MWE2.tex}{3}{c}
```

not:

```
\estauto{/tables/MWE2.tex}{3}{c}
```